# Maven build is successful, Eclipse detects cycle in dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, project, cycle

I'm working on a large project that consists of many smaller projects (about 140) that are all managed by maven. There is a master pom and a pom for each individual project.

Now I have introduced 2 new small projects, A and B, with the dependency A -> B. Furthermore B depends on another existing project C, so B -> C. A is used by another project D which is (as far as I've seen) independent from C. I'm not sure because the structure is very complex and I don't want to sit there sifting through poms all day.

This means I have a dependency graph like this: D -> A -> B -> C

When I build the master pom in maven (clean install) it finishes successfully. So does the eclipse:eclipse goal that generates the Eclipse project files. When I refresh the projects in Eclipse it rebuilds everything and finishes with the error "A cycle was detected in the build path of project...". This error occurs in about 30 of the 140 projects. Ofcourse Eclipse doesn't tell me what the cycle looks like...

How can it be that maven does not detect a cycle in the dependencies but eclipse does? I thought that the Maven Eclipse plugin just mapped the dependencies from the pom to the Eclipse .project and .classpath files?

The fact that Maven doesn't complain about cycles tells me that there is no dependency C -> D.

Comment: Important safety tip. Maven command line detects cycles within one reactor. If the cycle would only be exposed by activating a profile then your command line build will not report an error while your eclipse build may. If you try to debug this be sure to activate all the profiles to include all your modules (e.g., mvn -Pcore,buildtools dependency:tree) otherwise you may miss the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same symptoms but with no actual maven cycle.  I dealt with this in eclipse Indigo in a workaround fashion: I closed and deleted the eclipse projects that reported this error (not deleting the files making up the project), then re-created the maven projects in eclipse by importing the source files into my workspace with "File->Import...->Maven->Existing Maven Projects".  That took care of it.

Answer (score 1):

You may have dependencies with the scope test or runtime. Maven only looks for cycles in the compile phase. Eclipse or m2e doesn't differ the dependencies in scopes.

Comment: Argh! I forgot to include the new projects as modules in the master pom. So somehow that caused maven to not find the cycle. When I put the module definitions in maven also complained...

Fortunately maven told me where the cycle was and how the graph looked like. I identified the problem as an interface which was intended to decouple things. This needs to be in a separate project. Now the cycle is broken and things are fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have previous Eclipse settings on your projects, try this steps:

1. Remove all projects from Eclipse.
2. Run 'mvn clean eclipse:clean;'  from the console or delete all hidden files from all project folders: .project, .classpath, .wtpmodules, org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs, ...
3. Reimport the projects into Eclipse

This may fix the problem!